# Cannot find Error in code. Cannot GET

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

What's wrong with the following code?  We have all of our .html files in the app/public folder.  We tried running the following, but it doesn't not get the files.  It just says CANNOT GET.
Thanks so much!

```
var finalhandler = require('finalhandler')
var http = require('http')
var serveIndex = require('serve-index')
var serveStatic = require('serve-static')

// Serve directory indexes for public/ftp folder (with icons)
var index = serveIndex('app/public/index.html', {'icons': true})

// Serve up public/ftp folder files
var serve = serveStatic('app/public/')

// Create server
var server = http.createServer(function onRequest(req, res){
var done = finalhandler(req, res)
serve(req, res, function onNext(err) {
 if (err) return done(err)
index(req, res, done)
 })
})

// Listen
server.listen(5000)
```

Comment: Can you include complete error log? it might give others a clue.

Comment: Does the node process have read access to the folder  you're serving from?